# Django automatically converting double quotes to single quotes in text field

Tags: json, django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

I have a very basic django view and serializer and a Postgres database in conjunction with a popular package, dj-stripe. Dj-stripe is saving some json data in a textfield (column=`billing_details`) in the database, and it looks like so, with double quotes:

```
{"address":{"city":null,"country":null,"line1":null,"line2":null,"postal_code":"11111","state":null},"email":null,"name":"Jenny Rosen","phone":null}
```

Unfortunately, it seems that something (django? python?) is converting it to single quotes, (and adding some spaces after colons) as so:

```
{'address': {'city': None, 'country': None, 'line1': None, 'line2': None, 'postal_code': '11111', 'state': None}
```

My view is very basic:

```
class GetCustomerView(generics.ListAPIView):

  authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
  PaymentMethodSerializer

  def list(self, request):
    customer = Customer.objects.get(subscriber=request.user.organization_id)
    cards = PaymentMethod.objects.filter(customer=customer.djstripe_id)
    serializer = PaymentMethodSerializer(cards, many=True)
    pprint(serializer.data) 
    if cards:
        return Response(serializer.data)
    else: 
        return Response('error', status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)`
```

and my serializer is basic too:

```
class PaymentMethodSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  card = json.loads(serializers.JSONField())
  billing_details = json.loads(serializers.JSONField())

  class Meta:
    model = PaymentMethod
    fields = ( 'id', 'billing_details', 'card',)
```

Obviously it would probably be best stored in a JSONB field, but changing the package is not an option. That said, how do I go about preventing this conversion?

Comment: JSON fields will parse the contents in the database - in your case it will be converted into a dictionary which is what you are seeing when you print. This should not be an issue at all though

Comment: @IainShelvington Thank you... It is only an issue because the python dict is a pain to work with in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me was to set the serializer to a DictField

```
class PaymentMethodSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  card = serializers.DictField()
  billing_details = serializers.DictField()

  class Meta:
    model = PaymentMethod
    fields = ( 'id', 'billing_details', 'card',)
```

This caused the single quotes to come out as double quotes. Although this is a dict and isn't JSON (it takes a little more massaging to get to true json) this is a lot more friendly that having single quotes which are hard to replace. I don't exactly understand why a JSONfield doesn't serialize output to json by default, but maybe I have a lack of understanding.